# M2DOC DRepresentation isVisibleInDoc

Tags: m2doc

I am using Capella 1.4.0 and I would like to put my diagrams in my wordx using M2DOC, only if the attribute "Visible in documention" of the sheet "Management" is set to true.

I don't see the method isVisibleInDoc of the DREpresentation object.

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet, see https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/Capella-Extensions/issues/16

Comment: I made my own service and I want to get the value of the field "Visible in Documentation" but I was not able to get this value.

How can I take this value ? I see that this is not an attribute of the DRepresentation Class.

Comment: visibleInDoc is an EAttribute on EClassifier "PublishableElement" of Capella.
You probably want to take your DRepresentation, find its DRepresentationDescriptor, retrieve its target and check whether it is a PublishableElement.

Comment: thank you for your help. In fact I want to check the attribute of the diagram. My goal is to print or not the diagram according this value.